# High ping and low FPS when streaming with OBS on Twitch?

Tags: streaming, call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

My friend who is watching my stream of *Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare* has told me than the FPS is blocky and the gameplay stutters. I have also noticed that I have 1 red bar in game when playing. It's not laggy per se, but it takes the whole clip in a gun to kill someone and hitmarkers only appear after 4-5 seconds of shooting at someone.

My settings are like this:

- http://prntscr.com/82q06h
- http://prntscr.com/82q0gw

Is there anything I can do to decrease my ping (and increase the FPS) when streaming?

Comment: You have to make sure you have at least 1 or 2 Mbit/s more upload speed than the bitrate you are streaming with, otherwise you begin experiencing lag. Also make sure your PC (especially CPU) is good enough for x264's CPU encoding; it takes a good amount of resources.

Comment: I have 2,09 upload speed. So can you be a little more precize here and order me what to do?  :) thanks!

Comment: You are trying to stream at 3.5 Mbits and only have ~2 Mbits of upload speed? This doesn't work. Both you and your viewers get a bad streaming experience; you as the streamer experience severe lag/high ping in online games and your viewers might not even see the stream because twitch's automatic quality control gives your stream a bad rating. Refer to http://help.twitch.tv/customer/portal/articles/1262922-open-broadcaster-software, especially the line saying *"Max bitrate should be 3300 or 80% of your upload throughput, whichever is **lower**."*

Comment: Damn I changed the max bitrate to 1800 and buffer size to 1800 aswell but I still get one red bar in game..I changed the bitrate to 112 too. Any more help :/ ? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I've got it ! I've set the Buffer size and bitrate to 1600! Now I have 0 lag in game. normal and aweosme ping in game and streamers somehow get good quallity

Comment: You can mark your own answer as 'accepted' if you wish, by clicking the checkmark under the vote count. This way, future visitors to the question know you solved your issues :)